# How to resize an image to a certain height in ImageMagick 7?

Tags: imagemagick

I need to resize an image and the result image should have 300 pixels in height. The image must keep the aspect ratio of the original image.

Comment: `magick image.suffix -resize x300 output.suffix` See the answer below from `L. Scott Johnson`. For IM 7 use magick, for IM 6 use convert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specify the height and keep the aspect ratio, use `-resize x300`

```bash
magick in.jpg -resize x300 out.jpg
```

For more ways to specify the target size, see https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize

Comment: The `convert` following `magick` is superfluous and re-introduces old, pre v7 behaviour. Also, you should favour loading images **prior** to applying resizing or any other operators. In summary, `magick input.jpg OPERATOR ... output.jpg`